# ST_MakeValid for MultiSurface type in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, multi-polygon, collect

I am trying to take a lot of overlapping (bullseye type shape) polygons and curve polygons and create a valid shape with the correct cutouts. I was previously using a query that converted the curvepolygons to normal polygons with ST_CurvetoLine, then used ST_Collect and ST_MakeValid to create the multipolygon with cutouts. The issue is that the output has a lot of vertices.

Is there a way to do this without converting the curve polygons to lines/normal polygons?

I have read that a Multisurface could hold both polygons and curve polygons, but I'm not sure it's supported with the MakeValid Function.

Below is an example of one case I am working with.

The output I currently have isn't actually a curve, only many many vertices. I want to make sure that even with a mix of types I can get the correct output (ex: a regular polygon with a cutout of a curve polygon or vice versa )

[image]

Comment: Have you tried converting them back (`ST_LineToCurve`, `ST_ForceCurved`)?

Comment: since the original polygon has both lines and curves, that won't work. Do you know how to best approximate a curve using ST_CurvetoLine? I was to preserve as much of the area as possible @geozelot